# Listening on CTRL+C in Groovy Script

Tags: java, groovy

Is it possible to listen to CTRL+C when a groovy script is run from the command line ?

I have a script that creates some files. If interrupted I want to delete them from disk and then terminate.

Possible?

UPDATE 1: 
Derived from @tim_yates answer:

```
def withInteruptionListener = { Closure cloj, Closure onInterrupt ->

    def thread = { onInterrupt?.call() } as Thread

    Runtime.runtime.addShutdownHook (thread)
    cloj();
    Runtime.runtime.removeShutdownHook (thread)

}

withInteruptionListener ({

    println "Do this"
    sleep(3000)

    throw new java.lang.RuntimeException("Just to see that this is also taken care of")
}, {
    println "Interupted! Clean up!"
})
```

Comment: You probably want to call `removeShutdownHook` after `cloj()` has finished, as otherwise the hook will still get called at any point after the first `withInterruptionListener` call

Comment: Oh ( first comment missed the remove part ) ... that is a great idea!

Comment: Updated the code... also removed the CLEANUP_REQUIRED as it is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following should work:

```
CLEANUP_REQUIRED = true
Runtime.runtime.addShutdownHook {
  println "Shutting down..."
  if( CLEANUP_REQUIRED ) {
    println "Cleaning up..."
  }
}
(1..10).each {
  sleep( 1000 )
}
CLEANUP_REQUIRED = false
```

As you can see, (as @DaveNewton points out), `"Shutting down..."` will be printed when the user presses CTRL-C, or the process finishes normally, so you'd need some method of detecting whether cleanup is required

#### Update

For the sake of curiosity, here is how you would do it using the unsupported `sun.misc` classes:

```
import sun.misc.Signal
import sun.misc.SignalHandler

def oldHandler
oldHandler = Signal.handle( new Signal("INT"), [ handle:{ sig ->
  println "Caught SIGINT"
  if( oldHandler ) oldHandler.handle( sig )
} ] as SignalHandler );

(1..10).each {
  sleep( 1000 )
}
```

But obviously, those classes can't be recommended as they might disappear/change/move

Comment: Don't shutdown hooks run on termination regardless? I think you'd need to catch SIGINT.

Comment: @DaveNewton True, but without delving into the unsupported world of `sun.misc.*`, or JNI, I don't believe that's possible...  is it?  I'd probably just check if we'd finished the task or not in the `shutdownHook`, and delete files as appropriate...

Comment: @DaveNewton changed code to reflect your very valid point :-)

Comment: Yeah, not sure--checking for a finished flag might be the most reliable.

Comment: Thanks, nice workaround... that should probably work... if someone has other ways of doing this, i am interested to see it.

Comment: @Hamidam Updated answer to show how to do it with the `sun.misc` classes

Comment: @tim_yates thanks, great stuff! Now I am curios as about other stuff as well :) I would like to post what I came up with. Why won't they allow formatting in comments as well??!

Comment: I posted it in my question instead... I will look at teh sun.misc stuff as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not much into groovy script but i have a link that have some examples and says catching ctrl+c.....hope that helps http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_groovy/processmanagementetc.html

Comment: Yeah, although I could not found section 16.17 on that site... could you? See page link...

Comment: yes...that link is 16 chapter so just go on to 17 block of code...:-)